# Heatmap.2 color gradient with an additional solid color

Tags: r, colors, constants, heatmap

The heatmap I am using creates a gradient from 0.7 to 1.3 using `heatmap.2`:

```
heatmap.2(lifespan.matrix, col=bluered, breaks=c(seq(0.7,1.3,0.01)),
Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, trace="none", main="Lifespan")
```

In the heatmap you can see the gradient emerge ending oftenly in a solid blue line. This happens because of zero values in the matrix at these points.

[image]

I'd like to change this color, in the matrix noted as 0, into a different color i.e. yellow.
Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
breaks <- seq(0.7,1.3,0.01)
lifespan.matrix <- matrix(sample(c(breaks,rep(0,100)),100,replace=TRUE),nrow=10)
heatmap.2(lifespan.matrix, col=c("#FFFF00",bluered(length(breaks)-2)), breaks=breaks, Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, trace="none", main="Lifespan")
```

You specify the exact colors associated with the breaks.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and effective workaround is to replace your zero values with NAs in the matrix and colour them separately with the `na.color` argument of `heatmap.2`. See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031933/4477364