# Show R heatmap outliers in a different colour

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, heatmap

Looking to mark outliers in R matrix in a different color. 
Say I have the data as

```
1  2  4  2  5
5  4  3  2  3
1 500 5  4  2
```

Now I want to mark the 500 with a different color and the remaining of the matrix with default color of the heatmap.

Can someone guide me through the process?

Comment: This question is quite broad. There is no code and no data. Please add this so we can see what graphing system you are using, for example.

Comment: df is my dataset here..so whe i use the below function it gets plotted..but the color gradient difference between 1 2 3 etc is cannot differentiated. So, i want this 500 to come in some different color..may be green and the rest of the matrix in shades of other color.

heatmap(as.matrix(sapply(df, as.numeric))
,scale="column"
,col=heat.colors(256)
,main="Blah Blah"
,Rowv=NA
,Colv=NA
)

Comment: Please edit your question rather than add code into the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a decent workaround to achieve this. Using `heatmap.2()` from `gplots`, you can specify any colour for NA values in your heatmap. So, if you use a simple function to replace outliers with NAs in the source matrix, you can then represent them with any colour you like.

First, choose your outlier condition. For example's sake, let's just say that any value greater than 10 is an outlier.

```
> m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    4    2    5
# [2,]    5    4    3    2    3
# [3,]    1  500    5    4    2

m[m > 10] <- NA
```

Now plot the heatmap.

```
library(plots)
heatmap.2(m, trace = "none", na.color = "Green")
```

[image]

Outlier is now nice and obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clearly see the 500, you should specify no scaling.  For example,

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 5, 1, 2, 4, 500, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2), 
  ncol=5)

heatmap((m<500)+0, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.but what i want is 500 should be in a different gradient(may be green) and rest of the numbers in something else(may be orange).
Also i want the labels to come. Can you help