# How do you make a heat map and cluster with NA values?

Tags: r, heatmap, missing-data

I am trying to make a heat map using my data however struggle to code it properly.
My matrix is filled with log(x+1) values, this way I don't encounter log(0) errors however due to the nature of my data I have a bunch of 0 values and they mask any sort of trends the heat map could be showing.  Because of that I want to colour any 0 values grey or black and then the rest of my data colour along a blue-white-red spectrum.

Here is the coding I am using,

```
RHeatmap <- read.delim("~/Desktop/RHeatmap.txt", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red")) (n=20)
RHeatmap.matrix <- as.matrix(RHeatmap)
RHeatmap.matrix[RHeatmap.matrix==0]=NA

heatmap.2(RHeatmap.matrix,trace="none",col = my_palette, margins =  c(5,1),scale = "none", symbreaks = FALSE, Colv=TRUE, dendrogram="both",lwid=c(1.5,2.0))
```

When looking online for how to assign the 0 values a separate colour I noticed people assign them as N.As which can then be coded to appear a certain colour.  Question 1: How would I do that?

I also was wondering how I cluster with N.A values, when I tried I received an error saying you can't cluster with N.A values.
[image]

Comment: Yes you can indeed convert all your zero values to `NA` and then colour them separately with the `na.color` argument. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40031933/4477364).

Answer (score -2):

To get this to work you need to specify the breaks.**Note: There needs to be one more break than colors.**

```
library(gplots)

dat <- matrix(2**rnorm(900, sd = 5), ncol=9)
dat[sample(seq_along(dat), size = 180)] <- 0 ##setting some data to 0

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "orange", "red")) (n=20)
breaks <- seq(min(dat2, na.rm = T), max(dat2, na.rm = T), length.out = 21)

dat2 <- log2(dat+1)
dat2[dat2 == 0] <- NA
heatmap.2(dat2, trace="none", na.color = "black", scale="none", 
          col = my_palette, breaks=breaks)
```

[image]
**My two cents about your more general visualization question:**

1) All of your data is above 0 so I would recommend using a sequential color map, not a divergent color map. White tends to be viewed as 0, like in this case I see white and automatically thing it is `0`.

2) Your current heatmap looks good to me, i.e. well clustered and represented (color map aside). I'm not sure how much "better" it could get or what "better" would look like.

3) If your data has 0's in it I would keep them, so long as they are meaningful. This is very data dependent.

4) You could look into different distance metrics that may treat/weight 0 entries differently.

5) Setting `0s` to `NA` will change the clustering because distances are calculated on complete cases only, by default. See`dist` for more info.

Comment: 1) When I set my matrix to change 0 to N.As and set it to grey an error pops up saying " Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)" How do I fix this?
Can I set the 0s to a certain colour so it doesn't conflict with my clustering?

3) I figured I would keep the 0s to show a complete profile of the protein expression in the treatment conditions to show a full profile of proteins.  

Do you know of any good resources that explains the clustering, and binning well? I am extremely new to this and am not very educated in it.

Comment: 1. Check for `Inf/-Inf` values with `is.infinite`, because `log(0)` produces `Inf/-Inf` not NAs. 2. You can set 0's to a specific color (with the `col` argument and the color map you specify. But this has no effect on the clustering. 3. You could cluster on the non-zero data and then pass the dendrogram(s) to the heatmap and plot all data but only clustered on a subset of data.