# Using NA values with heatmap.2 and (specified) breaks

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap using heatmap.2 with the following break points:

```
breaks = c(-100000, -10000, -1000, -100, -20, 20, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)
```

The colors go from blue to red with white in the middle around the zero value (between -20 to 20) as specified by the color palette:

```
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red")) (9)
```

I would like to color the NA values black so they are distinguishable from the zero values in white. However, because I have NA values, the code I am using, which is:

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(MATRIX, col=colors, na.color="black", density.info="none", 
          scale="none", trace="none", Colv=FALSE, 
          breaks=c(-100000, -10000, -1000, -100, -20, 20, 
                   100, 1000, 10000, 100000))
```

creates the following error:

```
Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
```

I have already looked at the question posted here:
[How do you make a heat map and cluster with NA values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291051/how-do-you-make-a-heat-map-and-cluster-with-na-values)
which uses the following code for the breaks:

```
breaks <- seq(min(dat2, na.rm = T), max(dat2, na.rm = T), length.out = 21)
```

and colors:

```
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "orange", "red")) (n=20)
```

However, I can't get it to work with my list of specified breaks.

Below is a sample dataset like the one I am using:

```
Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 Gene6 Gene7
-100 -30 120 1790 NA 45 -1000
-4 0 -10000 10000 25 NA NA
1001 17 -4521 NA 123 31 12
NA 9087 NA -140 -1876 9087 3681
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

I have added below the actual matrix I am using:

`REP_1        DDIS_2        DDIS_3        DDIS_4        DDIS_5        DDIS_6        DDIS_7         OIS_8         OIS_9`

`CDKN2B     2.540990     32.074968  2.146586e+01  4.859826e+00 -2.938221e+12 -4.207584e+12 -1.837675e+13  5.967526e+07  2.196071e+13`
`FST    12225.652147     10.145169  2.528894e+00 -2.088704e+00  1.487618e+01  3.344373e+00 -1.652349e+00 -3.029684e+04 -1.021939e+06`

````
```DCN        1.070139     13.768018  1.333338e+03  1.959332e+00``` -1.707571e+01 -1.050936e+00 -2.748334e+02 -3.139434e+07 -1.367967e+17```
```E2F4      -1.320385 -42796.013849 -1.358740e+05 -1.550106e+05 -3.918849e+01 -1.039366e+02 -1.166989e+02  2.184948e+01  8.511640e+00```
```E2F5     126.816001     23.208083  5.867904e+00 -1.862336e+00 -2.909519e+00 -9.511401e+00 -1.112279e+03 -3.938015e+04 -7.241726e+00```
```EP300     -3.120860    -23.155158 -4.631832e+01 -4.389633e+01 -3.706228e+00 -6.220801e+00 -5.970081e+00 -2.154733e+00 -1.281695e+00```
```FBN1       2.000128      2.804892  1.334023e+00  1.129510e+01 -1.458580e+00 -3.180044e+00  1.471174e+00 -1.358247e+04 -3.097169e+09```
```FMOD              NA            NA            NA            NA            NA          NA```
````

Comment: Please always include `library` calls you're using, this time I've helped you.

Comment: I get no error. Would you mind to replace your data sample with the output of `dput(MATRIX)`. This is always the better method to provide data on Stack OVerflow, sice we also learn something about the `str`ucture of your data.

Comment: I have added some of the data I am actually using in case that helps. It is a numeric matrix

Comment: Ehm, did you read that `dput(yourMATRIX)` what asked?

Comment: Sorry, I tried head dput(MATRIX) as my matrix is huge. That is the output of that. I could attach a file?

Comment: Ah ok, you can also do `dput(mymatrix[1:6, 1:10])` for a subset.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, when the advice made me realise it was just my dataset I had a deeper look. If it's of interest, the heatmap.2 function didn't work, for me at least, if there were too many NAs. I got rid of the columns that were mainly NAs and then it worked ok. I guess it struggled to cluster them with so much missing data.